# Alterar campos de dados e label em um relatório Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, visual-basic-6, relatório, crystal-reports

Tenho um relatório e preciso alterar o layout, ou seja, remover um label e um dado e alterar outro label e outro dado. Tenho mover, mas não funciona. Veja a imagem e inclusive a versão do crystal.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso remover: `Data Ultimo Periodo:`
                 `Data de Admissao:`
e delocar para o lugar de data de admissao o `Data de Demissao:`

Claro, todos com seus respectivos dados(Campo que vem do BD)

Comment: obs: os campos estão cinzas e acho que por isso eu não consigo movê-los. Agora os labels não consigo, selecionar e nem tão pouco remover.

Comment: Consegui movimentar os campos de dados e remover, agora o label dos campos não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Percebi que é uma imagem os labels, está como picture1, mas não consigo editar. Como eu faço? Vou anexar os arquivos do relatótio, os .rpt e .ttx. Como eu faço para anexar um arquivo?

Comment: Como eu faço para anexar um arquivo?  Menu , inserir imagem

Comment: @Motta, é anexar arquivo aqui no SOpt e não no Crystal.